# How to shorten the signal of a car horn?

Tags: automotive

I installed an aftermarket alarm/keyless entry in my wife's car. Everything works well, however, she's not happy with how long the car horn is triggered. I've tried to simulate some circuits to shorten the horn signal and haven't been successful. The alarm/keyless controller is sounding the horn by grounding the horn ground wire. Any help is greatly appreciated before I just cut the connection entirely and remove the alarm/keyless horn functionality.

EDIT: I added a diagram. The controller is seems to be just grounding the speaker connection when it needs to sound the horn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo0YDj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could easily program a micro-controller to do what you want, if you're willing to build a circuit. Or even a (*shudder*) 555 timer one-shot circuit.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it but I know how people hate it when someone uses an IC to solve a problem when there's a simpler solution built from discrete components. Before I went the IC route I figured I'd ask the smart folks here.

Comment: MCUs actually ARE often the simpler solutions to an ever-increasing set of problems.

Comment: A simple high-pass filter (series cap, then resistor in parallel with zener diode from output to ground) would probably do the job if it is a digital off-on-off signal.

Comment: Ignore me, I misread the question.

Comment: Could you draw a diagram of how things are connected. That would help clarify things. If the circuit sounding the horn is just shorting the horn to ground, you can probably get away with just the capacitor, with resistor to +12V.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I added a diagram. Based on testing it seems like the controller is shorting the horn to ground like you mentioned. Is there a standard ratio of capacitor to resistor that will give me anticipated shortening of the signal? For example, 2:1 will half the signal length?

Comment: I've update my answer based on your new diagram.

Comment: Not likely. Car horns are typically on positive side relays. The alarm would ground the relay coil, not the horn negative.

Comment: Are you sure your alarm doesn't have a mute or chirp setting? What's the model number?

Comment: Is it grounding the horn or the horn relay? Big difference.

Comment: you could cheat and get 1 or 2 of those cheap timed relay modules that turn on/off w/delay...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You're correct. My apologies. It's definitely grounding the relay and not the horn directly. Again, my apologies. As far as the model number, it's a cheap aftermarket model. I'm not sure if I can post Amazon links, but it's the EASYGUARD EC003.

Comment: @Passerby You're correct, it's definitely grounding the relay. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvAOVg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. What you've got.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhDLR3.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A capacitor pulse method solution.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPiLB2.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. With the addition of a relay a very short delay timer can be created.*

How it works:

- At the instant of ALARM turning on the horn will sound.
- A very short time later RLY1 will energise, the contact open and the horn disconnect (and turn off).
- When ALARM turns off the relay drops out and the circuit resets.
- D1 prevents relay chatter when the horn button is pressed. It needs to be rated for the full horn current. It could be omitted if the chatter is not a concern.

The time delay will be a function of the response time of the relay.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to get a slightly shorter on time for the horn, and are not to fussed about the shape of the control signal, something like a simple high-pass filter should work:

[image: High-Pass R-C circuit for horn]

Size the capacitor to make the pulse wide enough for your needs. This will depend on the impedance of your horn.

The resistor can be pretty much anything (probably 10k to 100k).

The R-C circuit will basically act like an edge detector. When you pull the control signal low, it will pull the -ve terminal of the horn low for a short period of time until the capacitor charges up (essentially you get a spike of current). When you release the control signal, the diode will clamp any overshoot, and the resistor will discharge it ready for next time.

Comment: Just a point of clarification, the horn is being signaled from the alarm/keyless circuitry and seems to be just grounding the horn/speaker negative wire.